# XCTest always true for custom Swift error enum

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, enums

So I have a custom test enum like so:

```
enum RequestError: Error {
    case error1
    case error2
}
```

For some reason, `XCAssertEqual(.error1, .error2)` and `XCAssertEqual(.error1, .error1)` both always return true. I've implemented the Equatable protocol however this does not seem to help. Does anyone know why this is the case?

Just for clarity, here is my Equatable conformance:

```
extension RequestError: Equatable {
    public static func ==(lhs: RequestError, rhs: RequestError) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

(I intended to always return false)

Comment: Note that the `Equatable` protocol *requires* that `==` is an equivalence relation. In particular, `x == x` must always hold.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this might just be Xcode going crazy. It got to a point where the test passing was just not making sense (include a straight up XCFail()). I closed Xcode and opened it again and all seems to work now. Just FYI, I'm on Xcode 8.2 (8C38).